# Массив объектов и массивы свойств объекта, скорость доступа

Tags: c++, массивы, производительность

Здравствуйте.

Ниже два примера: в первом создаётся массив объектов со свойствами, во втором создаётся один объект, но на каждое св-во по массиву. Что-то мне подсказывает, что в обоих случаях скорость доступа к данным должна быть одинаковой, но в реальности она отличается и зависит от кол-ва свойств. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли ошибка в медленной версии и, если есть, как сделать правильно.

Пример 1, скорость выполнения 300 мс:

```
struct Item
{
    unsigned int p1;
    unsigned int p2;
    unsigned int p3;
    unsigned int p4;
    unsigned int p5;
    unsigned int p6;
    unsigned int p7;
    unsigned int p8;
    unsigned int p9;
    unsigned int p10;
};

void main()
{
    cout << "Start" << endl;

    clock_t time;

    unsigned int itemsAmount = 100000000;

    Item *items = new Item[itemsAmount];

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < itemsAmount; i++)
    {
        items[i].p1 = 1;
    }

    time = clock();

    unsigned int count = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < itemsAmount; i++)
    {
        count += items[i].p1;
    }

    cout << (clock() - time) << endl;
    cout << count << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Пример 2, скорость выполнения 30 мс:

```
struct Item
{
    unsigned int *p1;
    unsigned int *p2;
    unsigned int *p3;
    unsigned int *p4;
    unsigned int *p5;
    unsigned int *p6;
    unsigned int *p7;
    unsigned int *p8;
    unsigned int *p9;
    unsigned int *p10;
};

void main()
{
    cout << "Start" << endl;

    clock_t time;

    unsigned int itemsAmount = 100000000;

    Item *items = new Item;
    items->p1 = new unsigned int[itemsAmount];
    items->p2 = new unsigned int[itemsAmount];
    items->p3 = new unsigned int[itemsAmount];
    items->p4 = new unsigned int[itemsAmount];
    items->p5 = new unsigned int[itemsAmount];
    items->p6 = new unsigned int[itemsAmount];
    items->p7 = new unsigned int[itemsAmount];
    items->p8 = new unsigned int[itemsAmount];
    items->p9 = new unsigned int[itemsAmount];
    items->p10 = new unsigned int[itemsAmount];

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < itemsAmount; i++)
    {
        items->p1[i] = 1;
    }

    time = clock();

    unsigned int count = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < itemsAmount; i++)
    {
        count += items->p1[i];
    }

    cout << (clock() - time) << endl;
    cout << count << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: В ветку "Это классическая иллюстрация работы кэш-памяти." больше не разрешает добавить комментариев, поэтому пишу сюда.

@avp Процессор Intel Core i7-3820 @ 3.60 Ghz
@Flammable при itemsAmount=1000*1000 результаты такие:
Test N_Fields: 3 ms
Test N_Items: 4 ms

Comment: @sphere, замерам в единицах миллисекунд я бы особо не доверял. 

У Вас [L3 cache 10M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i7_microprocessors), все данные (~40Мбайт) не помещаются в кэш, а результат обратный предыдущему (там было 4гига).

Попробуйте погонять 1000х1000, сделав внешний цикл на 100 итераций, а также что-то промежуточное, скажем itemsAmount = 10000000 с 10 итерациями.

Comment: У меня c2q q9450 с 12MB L2, в кэш тоже не все не умещается, но struct of arrays быстрее, чем array of structs.

@sphere, покажите листинг assembly + source, может там оптимизации какие-то хитрые применились.

Comment: @Flammable, т.е. у Вас и ТС результаты противоположенные?

Comment: @avp , да.

Comment: Я тоже прогнал у себя для 10000000 элементов. 

g++.real (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3 компилил с -O2


    CPU                            N_Items   N_Fields  OS
    Dual-Core  CPU      E5400      160       320       Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
    Xeon(R) CPU         E5520      110       380       RHEL ... 6.0 (Santiago)


Интересная разница. 
Попробую еще вечерком дома на i5-2500.

Comment: Попробовал дома для 10000000 элементов. 

    CPU                            N_Items   N_Fields  OS
     Core(TM) i5-2500 3.30GHz      40        40        Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS

Добавил цикл на 10 итераций

    N_Items   N_Fields
    420       390

в среднем.

--

Пожалуй, можно сделать тривиальный вывод, что явно просматривается зависимость от модели CPU.

И отметить, что sandybridge очень быстро работает с памятью.

Comment: @avp провёл тесты, результаты такие:

N_Fields_1,  items: 1000*1000*100*5, iterations:100/5,   time: 3300
N_Fields_10, items: 1000*1000*100*5, iterations:100/5,   time: 29981
N_Fields_10, items: 1000*1000*100,   iterations:100,     time: 29547
N_Fields_10, items: 1000*1000*1,     iterations:100*100, time: 27535

N_Items_1,   items: 1000*1000*100*5, iterations:100/5,   time: 34387
N_Items_10,  items: 1000*1000*100*5, iterations:100/5,   time: 38377
N_Items_10,  items: 1000*1000*100,   iterations:100,     time: 39554
N_Items_10,  items: 1000*1000*1,     iterations:100*100, time: 36244

Comment: Исходный код тестов: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5ef9NXpTd2VNzFsc3BUd2k0UDg/edit?usp=sharing

N_Fields_1, N_Items_1: обращение к одному полю.
N_Fields_10, N_Items_10: обращение ко всем полям.

Comment: > И отметить, что sandybridge очень быстро работает с памятью.

Контроллер ведь встроенный.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это классическая иллюстрация работы кэш-памяти.

В первом случае разность адресов двух соседних элементов p1 равна sizeof(Item), во втором случае - sizeof(unsigned int), что в 10 раз меньше. Это означает, что во втором случае при последовательном чтении элементов p1 загрузка в кэш очередного блока памяти будет выполняться реже, что приведет к сокращению времени доступа к данным из этого блока. В вашем случае это дало выигрыш в 10 раз.

Comment: думаю, это раскрывает частично. Но все таки доступ у человека к памяти "последовательный". А в данном случае процессоры хорошо умеют подгружать в кеш.

Comment: @KoVadim, это как-то противоречит тому, что я написал?

Comment: Изменил код так, чтобы суммировались все св-ва.

В примере 1:
count += items[i].p1;
count += items[i].p2;
count += items[i].p3;
count += items[i].p4;
count += items[i].p5;
count += items[i].p6;
count += items[i].p7;
count += items[i].p8;
count += items[i].p9;
count += items[i].p10;

В примере 2:
count += items->p1[i];
count += items->p2[i];
count += items->p3[i];
count += items->p4[i];
count += items->p5[i];
count += items->p6[i];
count += items->p7[i];
count += items->p8[i];
count += items->p9[i];
count += items->p10[i];

Результаты:
Пример 1: 430 мс.
Пример 2: 300 мс.

Comment: @Flammable я не сказал, что противоречит. Но 10 раз - как то многовато. Но вот второй пример у @sphere - очень похоже на правду.

Comment: @KoVadim, 10 раз - это результаты его измерений, а не моих. Если действительно получились такие цифры, то спорить тут не с чем. Второй пример интереснее, поковыряю его у себя.

Comment: @Flammable похоже, что так и есть, как Вы написали.
Спасибо всем!

Comment: @sphere, вы не перепутали местами результаты? У меня первый тест выполняется быстрее.

Comment: @Flammable
Конечный файл, с которым я делал тесты (результаты, полученные на моей машине, подписаны в коде):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5ef9NXpTd2VRi1ZX24xeFR5RXc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @sphere, @Flammable, а модели CPU у вас какие?

Могу только предположить, что алгоритмы опережающей выборки в кэш из RAM у них разные. 

Т.е. с Test2 все очевидно, доступ к памяти чисто последовательный, причем каждое обращение в цикле приводит к выборке уже из кэша. Размер структуры 40 байт. Типичный размер cache line (выборка из RAM происходит такими порциями) -- 64 байта (не кратен размеру структуры).

А вот с Test1 интересней. Там в цикле происходят обращения к несмежным областям памяти. Т.е. за один цикл будет выбрано 10 cache lines (с длиной кратной int).

--

места мало...

Comment: В общем, я думаю, ход мыслей очевиден.

У кого сейчас есть свободное время, могут продолжить рассуждения.

Comment: Обновил файл, переназвал тесты.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5ef9NXpTd2VLTEyZ1FQSHhzQnM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @sphere, попробуйте прогнать эти тесты с itemsAmount=1000*1000. Мне пришлось это сделать, поскольку такого количества свободной памяти у меня нет.

Answer (score 0):

В первом случае выделяется один большой кусок памяти, размером в sizeof(Item), а во второй раз - много маленьких кусков по sizeof(unsigned int). Проблема - накладные расходы на кучу вызовов new несравнимо больше зависимости размера выделяемой области.

Comment: у человека как раз наоборот получается. У него куча выделений памяти работает быстрее:)

Comment: @KoVadim
Антинаучно!) Может из-за сегментации.

Comment: все по науке. просто нужно шире ее изучать

Comment: @KoVadim Очень эффектная фраза!)

Answer (score 0):

я взял и специально посмотрел разницу в скомпилированном коде между

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < itemsAmount; i++)
{
    items[i].p1 = 1;
}
```

и

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < itemsAmount; i++)
{
    items->p1[i] = 1;
}
```

Разница только в константах. И сильно повлиять на скорость работы не может. А вот выделить памяти на один гигабайт (около того) на большинстве современных машинах достаточно накладно (потому что памяти на большинстве машин все таки 4 гигабайта, и 2 из них - под ось). А память нужно одним большим куском.

Во втором случае выделям 10 кусков по 100М. И хотя это по размеру тоже, но найти куски такого размера сильно проще.

Хочу дома на 16 гигах протестить. Думаю, там разница в скорости выполнения кода будет в долях процентов.

Можете просто уменьшить кол-во запрашиваемой памяти и увидите, как скорость выполнения выровняется.

Comment: Тестировалось на машине с 32 Гб, откомпилировано для платформы x64.

Comment: linux/windows ? применялись ли флаги O1/O2 ?

Comment: Во втором случае обращений к памяти вообще может не быть, если items->p1 целиком окажется в кэше. Сами понимаете, какая при этом будет скорость.

Comment: KoVadim: Windows, флаг O2.

Comment: Комментарии под вопросом кончились... Поэтому (прошу меня извинить) решил продолжить здесь.

--

Пойдем немного дальше и разрушим идиллию последовательного доступа к памяти (и видимо зацепления конвейера в циклах). Добавим

       main (int ac, char *av[]) {
         ...
         for (i = 0; i < itemsAmount; i++) {
           int k = rand() % itemsAmount, save = i;
           if (av[1])
             i = k;
           count += items->p1[i];
           ...
           i = save;
         }

и аналогично для доступа в N_Fields тесте.

Естественно, тоже rand вносит свой вклад.

Comment: (продолжение).

При вызовах без аргумента получаем (последовательный доступ к памяти)
 одна итерация по 100000000 элементам


    N_Items   N_Fields
    110       120

а вот при случайном доступе картина разительно меняется

    N_Items   N_Fields
    870       3400 !!!

Почему возникла такая разница между доступом в N_Fields и N_Items?

Видимо сказывается влияние кэша, но понять, что именно тут происходит (как работает этот вероятностный механизм в том и другом случае), я не могу...

--

@sphere, а сделайте и опубликуйте [исследование](http://hashcode.ru/research/)